# mysql config, mysql5, macports, python, django

Tags: mysql, python, django, mac-osx

This is the settings.py file for python. I set mysql up via macports (mysql5 & mysqldb) 
The problem is that I am unsure if I have the configuration correct before I sync the db. The user name to connect mysql is different than the user with privileges on the db but the password is the same on both the connect & user with privileges. Which user name should go in the settings.py file? Port should be left blank, I believe the default is 3306. I hope that's correct?  thanks....

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'
        'NAME':   'jenniwren'                     # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '*****'                     # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '*******'                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock'                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username should be the MySQL user with rights to the database.  When you're logged on as that user, and enter:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

into the console, you should see a reference to the database name `jenniwren`.  As root, you can also do:

```
select Db, User from mysql.db where Db = 'jenniwren';
```

That will show which user(s) have privileges on that database.